# ADB is not starting no any error message

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Have searched about this issue, but nothing helped.
When i want to run my application in Android Studio(v1.2.2), window with text "Waiting for adb" appears.
In 30 seconds opens another window with error "ADB is not responding,if you want to retry please kill adb manually and click Restart".
It doesn't helps.
When i want to run adb start-server manually it doesn't show any message "./adb start-server

"
It is output in my terminal.
What i'm doing wrong?

output of adb:
"ddms: Unable to run 'adb': null
ddms: '/Users/farkhad/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary"

Answer (score 4):

Check port 5037 in my case java was listening to this port, i closed with task manager and solved y problem

Answer (score 3):

press ctrl+alt+delete in keyboard if windows  and start task manager and than end process for all  adb.exe you see in the processes tab

and than press the restart