# Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, google-pixel

After updating my android studio, I am not capable of anymore running applications on my google pixel because of that error. I need this help soon.

Comment: And what happens if you try `adb start-server` manually via a terminal as the error suggests you do?

Comment: And do you have anything already running on port 5037? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636163/adb-is-not-starting-no-any-error-message

Comment: I get -bash: adb: command not found. When I run emmulator, it works fine.Or my older samsung galaxy s3 device. But not the google pixel.

Comment: What if you open the terminal from the `platform-tools` directory and run `./adb start-server` (note the dot-slash)? And silly question, but have you rebooted your machine since the update in case it is a ports issue?

Comment: @MichaelDodd  the way you said it works, with everything. But if i have my google pixel plugged to my mac, it gives me again * failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon

Comment: and yes I have rebooted my machine.

Comment: seems same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665475/android-studio-adb-start-server-fails-adbkey-check-fails and its related to platform-tools 27.0